# Origin of Counter-attacking style of play in football?

Tags: football, history, strategy

Counter-attacking is one of the most used playing strategies in football. After searching for history of this style of play I came across [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football_tactics_and_skills#The_quick_counter-attack) and [Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/obituary-keith-newton-1165687.html) articles which mention the first use of counter-attack in football may have come from England's [Keith Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Newton_(footballer)) in 1970 World Cup quarter-final match against Germany, where he has set up goals for Alan Mullery and Martin Peters. So, my question is:

Is the aforementioned match the first one to use the counter-attacking style of play? And if not, which one was it and when did it take place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Herbert Chapman is believed to be the inventor of counter-attacking style of play. From [his Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Chapman#Northampton_Town), citing [Studd, Stephen (1998) - Herbert Chapman, Football Emperor: A Study in the Origins of Modern Soccer](https://books.google.de/books?id=p1VBAAAACAAJ&dq=9780285634169&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzzNbate3VAhVBXhoKHf4qDFIQ6AEIKDAA):

> Gradually, he created a style of highly-organised, counter-attacking
>   football, which was at odds with the prevailing orthodoxy but
>   nevertheless highly effective; Swindon Town's England international
>   Harold Fleming, after losing 4–1 at home to Northampton, remarked to
>   Chapman: "You have something more than a team: you have a machine."

Probably, **Swindon Town's 1 - 4 defeat to Northampton Town** during the period of 1907-1912, when Chapman was the manager of Northampton, was one of the earliest recorded matches that employed counter-attack.

This [TheGuardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2016/may/12/future-football-tactics-evolution-invoke-the-past) post also mentions Chapman being the one who practiced counterattacking style of play in the clubs he managed:

> Early football very much focused on having the ball and trying to make
>   use of it but, within 50 years, counterattacking had emerged, as
>   practiced by Herbert Chapman, first at Northampton and then, more
>   meaningfully, at Huddersfield and Arsenal.

Note that the counterattacking style of play was enhanced thanks to [WM formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_(association_football)#WM) that was also created by Chapman:

> The WM system, known for the shapes described by the positions of the
>   players, was created in the mid-1920s by Herbert Chapman of Arsenal to
>   counter a change in the offside law in 1925. The change had reduced
>   the number of opposition players that attackers needed between
>   themselves and the goal-line from three to two. This led to the
>   introduction of a centre-back to stop the opposing centre-forward, and
>   tried to balance defensive and offensive playing. The formation became
>   so successful that by the late-1930s most English clubs had adopted
>   the WM. [...] The gap in the centre of the formation between
>   the two wing halves and the two inside forwards allowed Arsenal to
>   counter-attack effectively. [...]

Here is the scheme of WM formation:

[image: WM formation] [(Source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_(association_football)#WM)